# Change fields in pdf using pypdf?

Tags: python, pypdf

i try to update entry-fields in a pdf using the following code with the pytho-module pypdf. At first i read the pdf-files and get all available fields on this firt pdf-page.

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("exmpl3.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

page = reader.pages[0]
fields = reader.get_fields()
for k,v in enumerate(fields):
  print (k, v)

writer.add_page(page)

writer.update_page_form_field_values(
  writer.pages[0], {0: "some filled in text"}
)

with open("filled-out.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
  writer.write(output_stream)
```

But when i run this program i get the following error-message:

```
C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\pypdf>python exmpl3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\pypdf\exmpl3.py", line 13, in <module>
    writer.update_page_form_field_values(
  File "C:\Users\WRSPOL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_writer.py", line 946, in update_page_form_field_values
    raise PyPdfError("No /AcroForm dictionary in PdfWriter Object")
pypdf.errors.PyPdfError: No /AcroForm dictionary in PdfWriter Object

C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\pypdf>python exmpl3.py
0 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[0]
1 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[1]
2 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[2]
3 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[3]
4 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[4]
5 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[5]
6 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[6]
7 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[7]
8 form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[8]
9 form1[0].#subform[0].CheckBox1[0]
10 form1[0].#subform[0].CheckBox2[0]
11 form1[0].#subform[0].CheckBox3[0]
12 form1[0].#subform[0].CheckBox4[0]
13 form1[0].#subform[0].CheckBox5[0]
14 form1[0].#subform[0].SSN[0]
15 form1[0].#subform[0].HouseholdIncome1[0]
16 form1[0].#subform[0].HouseholdIncome1[1]
17 form1[0].#subform[0].HouseholdIncome2[0]
18 form1[0].#subform[0].HouseholdIncome3[0]
19 form1[0].#subform[0].DateSigned[0]
20 form1[0].#subform[0].SignatureField1[0]
21 form1[0].#subform[0]
22 form1[0].#subform[1].Text38[0]
23 form1[0].#subform[1].RadioButtonList[0]
24 form1[0].#subform[1].DateRecordUpdated[0]
25 form1[0].#subform[1].DateSigned[1]
26 form1[0].#subform[1].SignatureField1[1]
27 form1[0].#subform[1].DateNotified[0]
28 form1[0].#subform[1]
29 form1[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\pypdf\exmpl3.py", line 13, in <module>
    writer.update_page_form_field_values(
  File "C:\Users\WRSPOL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_writer.py", line 946, in update_page_form_field_values
    raise PyPdfError("No /AcroForm dictionary in PdfWriter Object")
pypdf.errors.PyPdfError: No /AcroForm dictionary in PdfWriter Object
```

How can i update the fields in this pdf?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. What I did was to use a previous version of `pypdf`.

`pip install pypdf==3.8.1`

Comment: This answer seems far more helpful than setting up a if statement that may or may not actually fix the issue.

Considering I've been trying to get my script to read a single pdf for two days and fill it out with zero luck and on the first attempt, this simple action (rolling back to 3.8.1) solved ALL of my issues.... yeah.  Thanks mch22!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider copying the /Acroform object from your original pdf to your new one before attempting to update the page form fields.

```
if '/AcroForm' in existing_pdf.trailer['/Root'].keys():
    writer._root_object.update({NameObject("/AcroForm"): reader.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"]})
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code copies all the root objects (/AcroForm is a root object) from the reader to the writer fixing the raised PyPdfError("No /AcroForm dictionary in PdfWriter Object")

`writer.clone_reader_document_root(reader)`

Comment: ```clone_reader_document_root()``` also copies all the reader pages to the writer.

Answer (score 0):

To set the appearance stream in `pypdf==3.17.4`:

```
writer.set_need_appearances_writer()
```

---

### An example:

From https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/355

```
import pypdf
from pypdf import generic as pypdf_generic

# ... load file
reader = pypdf.PdfReader(file)
writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

writer.set_need_appearances_writer()

for page_nr, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
    form_fields = page.get('/Annots')
    if form_fields:
        for field in form_fields.get_object():
            field_object = field.get_object()

            # any other logic
            field_object.update({
                pypdf_generic.NameObject('/V'): pypdf_generic.create_string_object(field_value)
            })
    writer.add_page(page)

# create your output file or stream
writer.write(output_file)
```